How to aggregate data within the multiverse package in R
I want to perform a multiverse analysis using the multiverse package.
I have many different filters and data transformations to take into account the multiverse analysis.
One of them is the different way to aggregate the data, that can be:

mean
median
no aggregation

My first attempt is the following:
inside(M, {
  df <- sim_data %>%
  ## DATA TRANSFORMATION
    mutate( y= branch( data_transform, 
        "none" ~ y,
        "log" ~ log(y+ 0.1),
        "sqrt" ~ sqrt(y),
        "inverse" ~ 1/(y+ 0.1)
    )) %>%
  ## DATA AGGREGATION
    mutate( y= branch( data_aggregation, 
        "none" ~ y,
        "mean" ~ group_by(Condition, ID) %>% summarise(mean = mean(y)),
        "median" ~ group_by(Condition, ID) %>% summarise(median = median(y))
    ))
} )

Is this code going to transform the data and THEN aggregate the data?

using the multiverse package, what package are you referring to? Can you please add the library(xxx) line you are using. Also consider adding a minimal reproducible example, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/5963610/9462095
